# GORM get data from both tables on a one to one relationship

Tags: go, go-gorm

I have this two structs on my Go app

```
type Customer struct {
    ID             uint       `json: "id" gorm:"primary_key"`
    Name           string     `json: "name"`
    AddressId      int        `json: "addressId"`
    Address        Address    `json: "address"`
}

type Address struct {
    ID        uint   `json: "id" gorm:"primary_key"`
    ZipCode   string `json: "zipCode"`
    StreetOne string `json: "streetOne"`
    StreetTwo string `json: "streetTwo"`
    City      string `json: "city"`
    State     string `json: "state"`
    Number    string `json: "number"`
}
```

I'm using Angular at my front-end, so it would be very practical if I don't have to make two requests to get the Customer then the Address.

I searched in here but couldn't find an example for a one to one relationship, is there a way to make this query get not only the customer data, but also the address?

```
func (u customer) GetCustomers(params string) ([]models.Customer, error) {
    customers := []models.Customer{}
    u.db.Preload("Addresses").Find(&customers)
    return customers, nil
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you use the `Preload` function, you pass it the name of the field you want to load the data for.

In your case, it should look like this (because your field in the `Customer` struct is named `Address`):

```
u.db.Preload("Address").Find(&customers)
```

You can check out the [documentation](https://gorm.io/docs/preload.html#content-inner) for more details.

Answer (score 1):

I have these `two entities`, `UserAccount` with an ID field as a primary key, and `UserLoginData` with a `userId` foreign key. I want to `query UserLoginData by email` and retrieve all the values of `UserAccount` with the corresponding `userId`. I've done it as shown below. Although I can fetch the fields from `UserAccount`, I can't access some information like `firstName` and `userName` for `UserAccount`

```golang
// entities

type UserAccount struct {
    gorm.Model
    FirstName   string
    LastName    string
    UserName    string
    Gender      string
    Avatar      string
    DateOfBirth string
}

type UserLoginData struct {
    gorm.Model
    UserID                uint
    UserAccount           UserAccount `gorm:"foreignKey:UserID"`
    PasswordHash          string
}


// in repository
var user entity.UserLoginData
r.db.Preload("UserAccount").Where("email = ?", email).First(&user)
```